# Google Fit Distance data from API

Tags: php, api, google-fit

I am having some difficulties getting the distance walked from the google fit api and the documentation is less than helpful. I am using PHP to authorize adn grab the data into my web app, but so far distance has eluded me. From what a lot of people have mentioned you have to have access to the location

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read

That does return some values, but I am not 100% sure they are correct or need to be converted to miles/kilometers or something. so far I haven't found any formula for getting it to convert to what the app has recorded. Here is some data that I have recorded and whats coming back from those days for distance:

2020-07-12:

```
app: 3.66 miles
api: 5890.0519382954
```

2020-07-13:

```
app: 1.43 miles
api: 2308.7142831087
```

This is using the dataset

```
derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_distance_delta
```

Does anyone have any clue how to get the actual miles/kilometers out of the fit api? I have tried just about everything I can and am not able to get anything close to resembling an accurate response.

Comment: does this help? https://gist.github.com/abfo/1b16471efa78470535ecd0fb994a88a1

Comment: @Mech no, unfortunately not as that is the dataset I am currently using. The only difference between that code base and mine is the url, which I just replaced mine with his and it 404'd on me. my endpoint is

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources

Comment: [5890m is 3.66 miles](https://www.google.com/search?q=5890m+in+miles); [2309m is 1.43 miles](https://www.google.com/search?q=2309m+in+miles). (Just divide metres by ~1609). I'm not clear what you mean by "actual miles/kilometres", beyond this.

Comment: @AndyTurner you sir, are a life saver. I tried every metric except meters to miles as usually an API returns values in kilometers. I just over looked the meters aspect of it. Thats exactly the issue. The documentation never specified what metric the response value is returned in, at least not that I saw. Thanks a MILLION man!

Comment: @jeffro25 [the documentation says the units is metres](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/location#distance_delta).